# Update State in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a user Profile form where you can edit user's information such as name and age. I have 2 routes set up, the `/`which is for the main user component and the `/edit` which leads to the user Edit component. I have a `user` state that i am looping over to output `name` and `age` for a user in my `User` Component. I have added a method in my `User` component named `enterEditMode` which on click fetches `name` and `age` property of the user selected and then outputs that into the form in my `EditMode` Component. I am trying to create a method which `onClick` would update the name or age of the user. So i'd like to click on Sam and on the next page, update his name to `Samuel` and then click on `Update Info` button which should update the name `Sam` to `Samuel` on my `User` component page.

But i am having a hard time figuring out how i will do it.

Please check this complete working [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dijkstra-ntbz9?file=/src/components/EditMode.vue).

This is my Vuex Store:-

```
state: {
    user: [{ name: "Max", age: 29 }, { name: "Sam", age: 28 }],
    name: "",
    age: null
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: state => state.user,
    getName: state => state.user.name,
    getAge: state => state.user.age
  },
  mutations: {
    setName(state, payload) {
      state.name = payload;
    },
    setAge(state, payload) {
      state.age = payload;
    }
  }
```

This is my User Component:-

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-flex v-for="(user,index) in getUser" :key="index">
      {{ user.name }} {{user.age}}
      <v-icon @click="enterEditMode(index)">create</v-icon>
    </v-flex>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "User",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getUser: "getUser"
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      setName: "setName",
      setAge: "setAge"
    }),
    enterEditMode(index) {
      this.setName(this.getUser[index].name);
      this.setAge(this.getUser[index].age);
      this.$router.push({ name: "EditMode", params: { index: index } });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my EditMode Component:-

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-text-field solo v-model="name"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field solo v-model="age"></v-text-field>
    <v-btn>Update Info</v-btn>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getName: "getName",
      getAge: "getAge"
    }),
    name: {
    get() {
      return this.getName;
    },
    set(val) {
      return this.$store.commit("setName", val);
    }
  },
  age: {
    get() {
      return this.getAge;
    },
    set(val) {
      return this.$store.commit("setAge", val);
    }
  }
  },
  methods: {
    updateInfo() {
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thank you for all the help guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mutation in the store to update the `user` list. For instance to update the selected user name:

Create a `updateUserName` mutation, and make sure the `payload` contains both the user index and name to be updated:

```
mutations: {
  updateUserName(state, payload) {
    state.user[payload.index].name = payload.name;
  }
}
```

And then in the `EditMode.vue` file, let the set method of computed name to commit the `updateUserName` mutation we just created, keep in mind to pass in both the index and name properties:

```
name: {
  get() {
    return this.getName;
  },
  set(val) {
    return this.$store.commit("updateUserName", {
      name: val,
      index: this.index
    });
  }
}
```

Here `index` is another computed property taken from the route parameters for convenience:

```
index() {
  return this.$route.params.index;
},
```

Check the [CodeSandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-edison-rl4pj).

Comment: You sir are amazing. I wish i could upvote it more than once lol.